# How to pass an argument to kafka-console-consumer

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to read a message of size 3mb using kafka-console-consumer by running the command:

```
/bin/kafka-console-consumer --zookeeper myzookeeper:2181 --topic Topic1
```

However, I am getting exception:

```
2017-06-05 17:16:13,046] ERROR Error processing message, terminating consumer process:  (kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$)
kafka.common.MessageSizeTooLargeException: Found a message larger than the maximum fetch size of this consumer on topic Topic1 partition 9 at fetch offset 5. Increase the fetch size, or decrease the maximum message size the broker will allow.
    at kafka.consumer.ConsumerIterator.makeNext(ConsumerIterator.scala:90)
    at kafka.consumer.ConsumerIterator.makeNext(ConsumerIterator.scala:33)
    at kafka.utils.IteratorTemplate.maybeComputeNext(IteratorTemplate.scala:64)
    at kafka.utils.IteratorTemplate.hasNext(IteratorTemplate.scala:56)
    at kafka.consumer.OldConsumer.receive(BaseConsumer.scala:89)
    at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$.process(ConsoleConsumer.scala:110)
    at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$.run(ConsoleConsumer.scala:70)
    at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$.main(ConsoleConsumer.scala:48)
    at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer.main(ConsoleConsumer.scala)
Processed a total of 0 messages
```

Now i am trying to run the command:

```
/bin/kafka-console-consumer --zookeeper myzookeeper:2181 --topic Topic1 --args max.partitiion.fetch.bytes=10485760
```

But getting error:

```
args is not a recognized option
```

How can I pass the param `args` to kafka-console-consumer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to specify consumer properties in a file and supply it with `--consumer.config` parameter.

Comment: Thanks Dmitriy. I created a properties file with content: "max.partitiion.fetch.bytes=10485760". It worked.